# Delphi CopyMemory vs C++ memcpy

Tags: c++, delphi, memory, arrays

OK - So I never seem to have a simple question.

I have a custom library (which is not written by me) written in C++. This library does some network comms and I just pass some data to it as a byte array and retrieve a byte array from it on the other side. The library handles all the network stuff for me the sending/receiving of data to/from client/server.

So for example, I can write a client and a server. From the client I produce a byte array, the library takes the byte array and sends it to a server. The server I've written uses the same library to do the reverse, ie handle all the receiving of traffic and eventually passes back a byte array.

The library defines the byte array as part of a struct as follows... (I'm loading the library statically in Delphi, don't think that'll make a difference, but I am using FastMM4 - is this going to affect the memory sharing model between app and dll? Far as I'm aware using FastMM should be OK, have also tried ShareMem to no avail)

```
struct content {
  void *data;
  int size;
}
```

Anyway, from my client I am attempting to send "Hello"... the accepted wisdom is that the byte array data is copied into this struct by using memcpy like so...

```
char *data = "Hello";
memcpy((void *)content.data(), data, strlen(data)); // last parameter is length, ie 5
// network.sendrequest(content);
// where content.data() returns the aforementioned pointer
```

On my server I reply with "World". So the server replies as follows...

```
char *data = "World";
memcpy((void *)content.data(), data, strlen(data)); // last parameter is length, ie 5
// network.sendreply(content);
```

From a C++ client communicating with a C++ Server I receive this data on the server...

```
0x0035fdf6 "Hello" (or in Bytes... 72, 101, 108, 108, 111)
```

So after that essay, I think the C++ server code is correct because I can communicate correctly if I write a client in C++... But replacing the C++ client with a client written in Delphi doesn't work. I've replaced memcpy with CopyMemory, which I thought did the same thing but somehow my byte array is different by the time it reaches the C++ server... My Delphi client does the following...

```
// lDataPointer is a retrieved reference to the 
// pointer (void *data; see above) defined in the 
// C++ library. It appears to be a valid pointer at runtime...
lContentPointer := content.data(); // from DLL
// Where ByteArray is populated with byte data of "Hello" 
CopyMemory(lContentPointer, @ByteArray, 5); // Copy from Exe to DLL
// network.sendrequest(lContentPointer);

// I have printed the byte array before the CopyMemory to check 
// its contents before sending, which is '72 101 108 108 111'
```

So the data from the Delphi client appears correct, but the data received on the server is incorrect... Somehow "Hello" ('72 101 108 108 111') becomes

```
0x003efd96 "h,H" (or in Bytes 104, 19, 44, 2, 72)
```

I suspect I am doing something wrong with CopyMemory...? Or have I got the memory sharing wrong between the exe and the dll? How do I know what kind of memory model the C++ networking library uses? Or have I just copied that byte array incorrectly? Any help much appreciated...

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding something about DLLs. There is no "memory sharing model" between an EXE and a DLL - they run in the same address space. You can pass pointers back and forth and either the EXE or the DLL can read/write them without restriction. However a particular DLL might require you to copy parameters depending on its specific interface. In your case, who allocates the space for `content.data`? Are you possibly copying your data into random space determined by an uninitialised pointer?

Comment: try CopyMemory(lContentPointer, @ByteArray[0], 5);

Comment: I think that you forgot to copy the *last zero byte* in C strings. E.g.

    memcpy((void *)content.data(), data, strlen(data)+1); 

The C string convention is that strings should be terminated by a zero byte. Pascal (& perhaps Delphi, I don't know) might have a different convention (e.g. of starting strings with a word giving their length).

I can't answer your question related to `CopyMemory`.

Comment: @Greg...

No no, I think I understand them running in the same address space, a Delphi dll requires use of sharemem to share strings even in records and classes between the DLL and the Exe. Hence my query about memory sharing... Not sure that it applies to byte arrays...?

content.data is allocated by the networking library, and then I retrieve a reference to that pointer (I believe), so the pointer should be initialized correctly... Debugging I can get a valid pointer address back for lContentPointer - in my run just now the pointer is $18F50E, which I assume is valid?

Comment: @Dorin... That solves it! But could you tell me why?? ie, why doesnt ByteArray work?!? as opposed to ByteArray[0]?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
CopyMemory(lContentPointer, @ByteArray, 5);
```

The error is that `ByteArray` is, effectively, a pointer to the first element of the array. You are thus passing the address of the pointer to the first element of the array. In other words you have an extra, spurious, level of indirection. You need

```
CopyMemory(lContentPointer, @ByteArray[0], 5);
```

or

```
CopyMemory(lContentPointer, Pointer(ByteArray), 5);
```

---

As for `CopyMemory` vs `memcpy`, the former is a Win32 API function and the latter is a C standard library function. The two functions perform identical tasks and are interchangeable.

Comment: @0909EM yes, he's the active Delphi expert around here, +1