# ByteArray from C++ Library crashes Delphi at DynArrayClear

Tags: c++, delphi, memory, arrays

I'm still having trouble with the same application as mentioned here
[Delphi CopyMemory vs C++ memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671728/delphi-copymemory-vs-c-memcpy)

Whilst I had a satisfactory answer to my original question, I'm struggling to understand a subsequent crash...

I have a delphi app, that uses a networking library and a server app (that exists somewhere on the work) which uses the same networking library. The networking library appears to work correctly is written in C++ (not by me). The library handles all the communications for me, so I need only supply an array of bytes to the library. I can successfully send to, and receive data from my server - And the data is correct in both directions.

I receive data from the server in a helper procedure. The procedure runs correctly to the "end;" (quite literally). The procedure ends (I'm successfully through all comms at this stage and now solely concerned with Delphi), and the debugger takes me into _DynArrayClear - where my application crashes. From the help I read "The Delphi compiler automatically inserts calls to this function whenever appropriate."

I'll add some more background if it helps... The networking library populates a byte array which is defined as void *data in a content struct (see below)

```
struct content {
  void *data;
  int size;
}
```

I believe all I need to do, once this data is populated is perform a CopyMemory operation in Delphi...

Could someone please help me understand what I've done wrong?!

```
// should be: function THelper.ReceiveData: TBytes; - 
// but my crash happens with either a function or a procedure
procedure THelper.ReceiveData; 
var
  lMsg: Pointer;
  lSize: Integer;
  lData: TBytes;
  lRecvResult: Integer;
begin
  lMsg := nil;

  // Remote call to receive data returns an integer indicating success
  lRecvResult := lib_receive_data(lMsg, Integer(Flags));
  TUtils.CheckError(lRecvResult);

  SetLength(lData, 5);
  CopyMemory(@lData[0], lMsg, 5); // where 5 is the length of data to copy
end; // takes me into _DynArrayClear 



// The application crashes after exiting _DynArrayClear 
// For clarity @@noFinalize is entered at line 20795
// I get all the way to the 'end;' at line 20801 in System.pas
// 
// Then from _DynArrayClear I press F7 and immediately get access violation at 0xcdcdcdcd: read address of 0xcdcdcdcd and the following is the call stack...

:7789fada ntdll.NtQueryInformationProcess + 0x12
:77890143 ntdll.KiUserExceptionDispatcher + 0xf
:778c6a8b ; ntdll.dll
:77890143 ntdll.KiUserExceptionDispatcher + 0xf
:778c6a8b ; ntdll.dll
:77890143 ntdll.KiUserExceptionDispatcher + 0xf
:778c6a8b ; ntdll.dll
:77890143 ntdll.KiUserExceptionDispatcher + 0xf
:778c6a8b ; ntdll.dll
:77890143 ntdll.KiUserExceptionDispatcher + 0xf
:778c6a8b ; ntdll.dll
:77890143 ntdll.KiUserExceptionDispatcher + 0xf
:778c6a8b ; ntdll.dll
:77890143 ntdll.KiUserExceptionDispatcher + 0xf
:778c6a8b ; ntdll.dll
```

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think your issue is using `TBytes`; have you tried `TByteArray` or `PByteArray` instead?

Comment: The lData dynamic array is local to your procedure. It is automatically destroyed when it goes out of scope, i.e. when exiting the procedure. I cannot yet figure out why you get an exception though.

Comment: I have tried both TByteArray and PByteArray... Same problem, which makes me wonder whether its the void *data which is being deleted twice or not at all? My tired eyes don't know the answer to this one

Comment: Your procedure does not free any memory from what lMsg points to. That thing is ok. Have you checked that `lMsg` is <> nil before the `CopyMemory` ? And have you tried embracing the CopyMemory with `try .. except` ?

Comment: Looks like the stack is broken. Check calling conventions for `lib_receive_data` declaration in C and Delphi code.

Comment: @Serg What makes you think that? It looks more like a heap corruption to me.

Comment: There's not enough in the Q to say much. It would appear to me that you have corrupted the heap but it's hard to say. I've no idea why you talk about `struct content` and then make no further mention of it.

Comment: @David Judging by the above code the only possible explanation is wrong calling convention, with a corrupted stack as a result. Sure if a bug is somewhere else heap corruption is possible too.

Comment: @serg my assumption is that heap is corrupted elsewhere

Comment: @David I don't really care what memory is corrupted. Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> lRecvResult := lib_receive_data(lMsg, Integer(Flags));

What is the first parameter of `lib_receive_data()` actually declared as?  You are passing in a local `Pointer` variable that is initially set to `nil`, so I assume the parameter is a `var` that get assigned some meaningful memory address when `lib_receive_data()` exits?  What does `lib_receive_data()` actually output?

You meantion a `content` structure, but I don't see you using it anywhere. And you declare an `lSize` variable, but you do not use it, either.  What does the documentation for `lib_receive_data()` actually say?

> SetLength(lData, 5);
>    CopyMemory(@lData[0], lMsg, 5); // where 5 is the length of data to copy

Are you absolutely sure that `lMsg` always points to a bufer that contains at least 5 bytes?  What does the return value of `lib_receive_data()` represent?  It is a byte count, or just a status code?

The fact that you are getting errors at an address like `0xcdcdcdcd` suggests you are likely trampling the `TBytes` memory, which would lead to a crash in `_DynArrayClear()` when the `TBytes` is being deallocated.